# How do I setup Magical Record in a NSPersistentDocument app?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, core-data, magicalrecord, nspersistentdocument

I'm learning to develop cocoa apps, yet I'm jumping straight to Core Data. Well, it seems to be the right way to write the app I want. So, I've been looking into [Magical Record](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord) and found [this really helpful tutorial](http://yannickloriot.com/2012/03/magicalrecord-how-to-make-programming-with-core-data-pleasant/#sthash.d2iaGJ47.dpbs) which explains how to setup Magical Record on your AppDelegate.

Problem is I'm building a document-based app, so I have a context per `NSPersistentDocument` which is magically setup and available for me through the `managedObjectContext` property.

So, first, I don't know if I should hook up MR to this context or override the Core Data's stack creation in my document class to use MR.

So how do I setup Magical Record here?